# How to use Google Book API in Android to download/search books

Tags: android

I'm new  to android and trying to build this application

1. As a user, I will be entering some terms in application. Service  will search for books relevant to those terms on the internet using Google Book API. It will fetch the information and store in content provider. In case term is already present, then service will check if there is any change in content. In case, there is change, service will notify the user using notification API.
2. When user starts application, or click on notification, he will be shown the latest relevant books. For this purpose, Activity will directly talk to content provider using content resolver

I'm enable to find anything on Google Book API though I got Google Book API docs but how to start or implement them in my program is still unknown to me

Comment: Pardon me! Sir, You mentioned "Google Boob API" in 2nd last line :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. First just write an application that uses HttpClient to invoke a url and get the data back.  Study HttpClient api, and sample apps that use HttpClient to connect to server because thats what you are going to be doing.  I would recommend using the REST API, but this is still a style of URL and interaction.  Its still fundamentally an HttpClient interaction scenario.  So you will need to get a google account for credentials, and download the jar files for the Book API if there is on.  create a libs folder in your eclipse android project (definitely use eclipse), use exactly the folder libs to place the jar files for Google API and start coding!